# What does the "!" character do in nodejs module names?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amd, intern, node-modules

I've started using *the intern* library to write functional tests in js, and I realized that I couldn't understand this syntax:

```
var assert = require('intern/chai!assert');
var registerSuite = require('intern!object');
```

What is the purpose of the `!` character in the argument of the `require()` method?

Comment: https://github.com/theintern/intern-tutorial

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Short answer**

It identifies a resource that is part of a plugin.
The structure of the identifier is: `[plugin]![resource]`.

**Long answer**

In the [documentation](https://theintern.github.io/intern/#conventions), you can find that:

> Intern is built on top of a standard amd loader, which means that its modules are also normally written in the AMD module format.

That's why and how the `require` function is actually injected, so it's clear that you are not using the `require` module provided along with *Node.JS*.

It states also that:

> [AMD format] Allows modules and other assets to be asynchronously or conditionally resolved by writing simple loader plugins

If you follow the [link](https://github.com/amdjs/amdjs-api/blob/master/LoaderPlugins.md) provided with the documentation when it cites the loaders, you find that:

> Loader plugins extend an AMD implementation by allowing loading of resources that are not traditional JavaScript dependencies.

In particular, you can find that a dependency has the following form:

```
[Plugin Module ID]![resource ID]
```

It goes without saying that the default implementation of the *loader* you get by using *intern* adheres to the above mentioned standard.

That said, it follows that, if we consider:

```
intern/chai!assert
```

You can read it as `inter/chai` as plugin module and `assert` as actually required resource.

The purpose of the *!* character in the argument of the `require()` method is to satisfy the requirements of the syntax used to identify a resource that is itself part of a plugin.

Answer (score 4):

I got this answer for you extracted from this [similiar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18512503/can-someone-explain-the-syntax-involved-in-this-require-js-example) and very well explained by [explunit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/151212/explunit):

> The exclamation point syntax is reserved for plugins. Typically there would be something else following the exclamation point which indicates the resource that the plugin would load, e.g. text!myTemplate.html, but in the case of domReady! the plugin exists just as a way to wait until DOM loaded before invoking your callback function, so nothing needs to follow the exclamation point.