# What does "string!" mean?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to modify the popular [Energy-skate-park](https://github.com/phetsims/energy-skate-park-basics)
simulation so that it launches with the grids visible. While looking at the code I came across declarations like the following:

```
var energyEnergyString = require( 'string!ENERGY_SKATE_PARK_BASICS/energy.energy' );

var energyKineticString = require( 
'string!ENERGY_SKATE_PARK_BASICS/energy.kinetic' );
```

I have no idea what this "string!" followed by some file path means. Is it angular? Is it vanilla JS feature?

Can anyone please guide me to the right direction/documentation to understand these declarations better?

Comment: Here's an answer for require.js: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18512503/can-someone-explain-the-syntax-involved-in-this-require-js-example

Comment: I dont mind the negative vote if i asked a stupid question. But at the same time explaining or trying to answer my question will help me to not receive more negative points!! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This is probably a [`webpack-loader`](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/), in your case, [`string-loader`](https://github.com/enmoon/string-loader) that transforms the required file to a string.

Comment: count it be grunt? In my project i cannot seem to find any reference to webpack.

Comment: it is a path declaration prefixed with a type, it is not vanilla javascript, it is a plugin library